# What are these controller parameters in controller file?

Tags: angularjs

I am turning over my head to understand AngularJS. I am unable to make sense of this. Online guides are only basic as far as I have seen.

```js
app.register.controller("viewTests", [
  "$scope",
  "$modal",
  "$http",
  "$route",
  "pinesNotifications",
  "$location",
  "$route",
  "$routeParams",
  "$timeout",
  "$modal",
  function (
    $scope,
    $modal,
    $http,
    $route,
    pinesNotifications,
    $location,
    $routeParams,
    $timeout
  ){
```

Please explain to me:

1. How do they work and interact?
2. Is the parameter order important?

Comment: It's how Angular manages dependency injection. It's well documented [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di).

Comment: The array/func params here don't match.

Answer (score 1):

The convention that you are using is one of the convention that can be used with angular. In that particular convention, you are injecting the dependency as well as using them for that particular controller, and order of the dependencies matters for that, else your use of dependency won't work as you are expecting.

```
app.register.controller('viewTests',function($scope, $modal,$http,$route,){

})
```

In the convention above, the order does not matter. I believe i have answered your number 2 question.

Now, for number 1 question. The working logic is similar to normal require that you use in javascript, however in angularjs you have a main module where you inject all your dependencies, and access them on your controllers. There are certain dependencies that are readily available in `angularjs` such as `$scope`, `$http`. However, if there are any external plugins that you require, then you inject it in your main module. For example: In order to use `$state` in the controller you would require the `'ui.router'` which you inject as follows.

```
var app = angular.module('yourAppName', ['ui.router']);

app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

    $stateProvider

        // HOME STATES AND NESTED VIEWS ========================================
        .state('home', {
            url: '/home',
            templateUrl: 'partial-home.html'
        })

        // ABOUT PAGE AND MULTIPLE NAMED VIEWS =================================
        .state('about', {
            // we'll get to this in a bit       
        });

});
app.register.controller('viewTests',function($scope, $state){

})
```

Likewise, you inject the necessary dependency and use only necessary dependencies in your controller as well.

Comment: Can you please tell me what other conventions are there

Answer (score 0):

1. These are injections, like your scope or the http service for http actions. you will find most of them well documented, because they are part of AngularJS. for example: [`$http`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)
2. Order is not important inside the array (I assume you forgot the closing bracket) but the parameter order of the controller is important.